# Can I force NFS automounts to use NFSv3?

Tags: fedora, autofs, automount

I have a linux server that is exporting NFSv4 as well as NFSv3. I have a Fedora14 client that is defaulting to NFSv4 when automounting NFS shares off of the linux server, and it seems to be causing some problems. All my other linux clients on the network are mounting via NFSv3 without issue, so is there a way I can tell automount to mount the share via v3?

I am pulling my automount maps via LDAP, with an entry in my /etc/auto.master file like so:
`+auto_master`, so I assume it's a bit different than listing options with a regular automount map?

(.i.e. `/home --nfsvers=3 fileserver:/DATA`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In /etc/sysconfig/autofs, change the MOUNT_NFS_DEFAULT_PROTOCOL variable.

```
# MOUNT_NFS_DEFAULT_PROTOCOL - specify the default protocol used by
#                              mount.nfs(8). Since we can't identify
#                              the default automatically we need to
#                              set it in our configuration. This will
#                              only make a difference for replicated
#                              map entries as availability probing isn't
#                              used for single host map entries.
#
#MOUNT_NFS_DEFAULT_PROTOCOL=3
MOUNT_NFS_DEFAULT_PROTOCOL=4
```

Comment: This definitely seems to be the way to do it -- but I'm still seeing vers=4 in my mount when running the `mount` command (This is after restarting autofs and rebooting).

Comment: Okay, so I've got this working. I also needed to change the Defaultvers= and Nfsvers= values in /etc/nfsmount.conf. Now it's mounting with NFSv3.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple different automount schemas out there, and I'm not sure you're using the same one we are. But, we have LDAP entries like:

```
dn: automountKey=jon166t,automountMapName=home.map,dc=cs,dc=brown,dc=edu
objectClass: automount
automountKey: jon166t
automountInformation: -intr,proto=tcp nfs.cs.brown.edu:/gpfs/main/home/jon166t
```

The "automountInformation" attribute is literally just a string, as it would have been on the RHS of a static automount map, or one in NIS, etc.

We have CentOS 5, Debian Etch (oldstable), and Debian Lenny (stable) pointed at these maps.